# Jface Text with predefined input and suggestion for user

Tags: swt, jface, e4

Problem Statement:
I as a user needs text box that selects from one of the existing options that is pulled from database and also give suggestions as the user is typing in the text box.

Possible Solution:
I know one possible solution is combo box but I do not user to have a large dropdown every time he wants to input in a text box and at same time I need user not to add new value. Also I want user to have suggestions for user from possible input values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AutoCompleteField` to add automatic completion suggestions to various types of control such as `Text`.

For example:

```java
String [] proposals = .... array of completion proposals

Text text = new Text(parent, SWT.BORDER);

new AutoCompleteField(text, new TextContentAdapter(), proposals);
```

As the user types in the text field matching proposals will be shown in a drop down. They can select the one they want or just continue to type.

Use `ComboContentAdapter` instead of `TextContentAdapter` to make this work with a `Combo` control.

You can also use `ContentProposalAdapter` if you need more control of the proposal behaviour, `AutoCompleteField` just provides a simpler interface to this.

Comment: Will ComboContentAdapter avoid the drop down as this field can have more than 1000 values as input and I dont want a huge dropdown

Comment: The drop down always works the same, it only shows matches for the text that has been typed.